# Flatten self referencing object in Auto Mapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a self referencing model that I would like to convert to a flat list. The model looks like this.

```
public class Node
{
    public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class NodeDTO
{
    public PersonDTO Person { get; set; }

    public LanguageDTO Language { get; set; }
}

public class NodeListDTO
{
    public List<NodeDTO> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

I want all nodes in the hierarchy to be flattend to one single list in my DTO object. Is this possible with Auto Mapper.

I have tried to use a Custom Value resolver but I haven't figured out how to use the mappings for PersonDTO and LanguageDTO inside the value resolver.

Comment: It's not about mapping Node to DTO. It's about wrapping nodes. You can use Automapper here. But all mapping you should do manually. Also it's not clear whether you want to preserve inner nodes list of each node.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Can you explain a bit more elaborately what you mean with wrapping nodes? By manually, do you mean I need to do a custom value resolver for all models? The inner nodes list should not be preserved (see updated question)

Comment: Why explain if you have edited question and replaced `List<Node>` with `List<NodeDTO>`? What mapping do you have now? Did you try something?

Comment: Can you clearly specify "what to what" do you want to convert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you will need code to flatten nodes hierarchy. AutoMapper will not do that automatically. I use following extension methods for that:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this T root,
   Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsValueType && root == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(root));

    return Flatten(new[] { root }, childrenSelector);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    if (childrenSelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(childrenSelector));

    return FlattenIterator(source, childrenSelector);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> FlattenIterator<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    if (source != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return item;
            var children = childrenSelector(item);
            if (children != null)
                foreach (var child in FlattenIterator(children, childrenSelector))
                    yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

Next - you need to tell AutoMapper how to flatten and map nodes hierarchy to list

```
MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
{
    c.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>();
    c.CreateMap<Language, LanguageDTO>();
    c.CreateMap<Node, NodeDTO>();
    c.CreateMap<Node, NodeListDTO>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Nodes, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.Flatten(n => n.Nodes)));
});
```

And now you can simply use

```
var node = new Node {
    Person = new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Bob" },
    Language = new Language { Id = 10, Code = "en" },
    Nodes = new List<Node> {
            new Node {
            Person = new Person {  Id = 3, Name = "Mike"},
            Language = new Language {  Id = 11, Code = "es"},
            Nodes = new List<Node> {
                    new Node {
                    Person = new Person {  Id = 4, Name = "Alex"},
                    Language = new Language {  Id = 11, Code = "es"}
                }
            }
        },
        new Node {
            Person = new Person {  Id = 5, Name = "Serge"},
            Language = new Language {  Id = 12, Code = "by"}
        }
    }
};

var nodeListDTO = mapper.Map<NodeListDTO>(node);
```

Result:

```
{
  "Nodes": [
    {
      "Person": { "Id": 1, "Name": "Bob" },
      "Language": { "Id": 10, "Code": "en" }
    },
    {
      "Person": { "Id": 3, "Name": "Mike" },
      "Language": { "Id": 11, "Code": "es" }
    },
    {
      "Person": { "Id": 4, "Name": "Alex" },
      "Language": { "Id": 11, "Code": "es" }
    },
    {
      "Person": { "Id": 5, "Name": "Serge" },
      "Language": { "Id": 12, "Code": "by" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but I updated my question and can't get your answer to work. I'm having problem with 

.ForMember(d => d.Nodes, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => s.Flatten(n => n.Nodes))); 

n is of type ResolutionResult and therefore has no member called Nodes.

Comment: @Abris I'm sorry, but I rolled back your changes. You should not add modifications which invalidate answers. There are several overloads of `ResolveUsing` one of them accepts `Func<TSource, object` make sure you are calling correct one.

Comment: Ok, fine but to my defence my modifications was made before you answered

Comment: @Abris no problem here, just for future - some users modify questions dramatically or even start adding new questions to first one. So it's always better to start new question :)