# Map a member of a member to the current class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have an EF model with Vehicle.Applications.Warranties, and I'm mapping to VehicleDto.  I want the Warranties in VehicleDto and I have a WarrantyDto to receive it.  I keep getting null for Warranties, though.

I'm using a projection which might be wrong, but from the AutoMapper docs, I can't see any other way to access IQueryable interfaces like this.

This is what I've tried.  Doesn't seem to work.

```
CreateMap<Vehicle, VehicleDto>();
CreateMap<Warranty, WarrantyDto>();
CreateProjection<Vehicle, VehicleDto>().ForMember(d => d.Warranties, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Applications.Select(a => a.Warranties)))
```

Comment: That's not possible and that's a *good* thing.  `AutoMapper` is meant for simple, convention-based mappings in the `Select` clause. `s.Applications.Select(a => a.Warranties)` is a full-blown 3-table subquery - EF will have to generate a subquery that JOINS with `Vehicles` with `Applications` and then `Warranties`. That's a very expensive operation

Comment: Right.  I want to flatten complex types here.  In fact, in the Flattening section it shows that I can aggregate a list of OrderItems into GetTotal => _orderItems.sum(s => s.price);  which will map to foo.total (something like that).  What's the difference between that and GetWarranties => foo.Application.Warranties.  Also, it's not an overly expensive operation.  It's the same operation that I would have to make if I had VehicleDto, ApplicationDto, and WarrantyDto which works.  It makes a single SQL call.

Comment: Why does `.ForMember(d => d.Label, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Coverage.Label))` work then?

Comment: Try writing the LINQ query without AutoMapper to see why. `s.Coverage.Label` can easily appear in the `Select` clause, but not `s.Applications.Select(a => a.Warranties)`. You'd need to add a `from app in vehicle.Applications from warranty in app.Waranties` clause or a `SelectMany()` to map all the way to the Waranties. `AutoMapper` can't change how EF Core itself works. That's not what it's meant for

Comment: Check this related question [How to use Automapper to flatten list of entity hierarchies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510650/how-to-use-automapper-to-flatten-list-of-entity-hierarchies). You'll have to either use `SelectMany` explicitly, or start the query from `Applications`

Comment: That should be fine. The thing to check is how you are executing your mapping. If you have an `IQueryable` of Vehicles  then you can use Automapper's `ProjectTo` in place of something like `Select(x => Mapper.Map<VehicleDto>(x))`.  If you are using `.Map<VehicleDto>` and cannot use `ProjectTo<T>` then you need to eager-load the Vehichle.Application and Vehicle.Application.Waranties if lazy loading is disabled.